# Roslyn rewriter: Remove Conditional from Expression

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to do a rewriter in order to convert expressions like:

```
args[0]?.ToLower().StartsWith("x")
```

into

```
args[0].ToLower().StartsWith("x")
```

My idea was to create a MemberAccessExpressionSyntax node where the left part would be `args[0]` and the right part `ToLower().StartsWith("x")`.
However MemberAccessExpressionSyntax only accepts as left part an Expression (no problem here) but the right part a SimpleNameSyntax, which is not the case here.

Any ideas how to do it in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

The right part can't be `ToLower().StartsWith("x")`, the tree wouldn't make sense this way, because `ToLower().StartsWith("x")` is not a *member* of `args[0]`.

Instead, you need to reference `ToLower` in the right part, then wrap everything into an `InvocationExpression`, and *then* wrap everything again into an `InvocationExpression` with a `MemberAccessExpression` (the code thus far is the left side), with `StartsWith` as the right side.

Something like this:

```
InvocationExpression - args[0].ToLower().StartsWith("x")
    MemberAccessExpression - args[0].ToLower().StartsWith
        InvocationExpression - args[0].ToLower()
            MemberAccessExpression - args[0].ToLower
                ElementAccessExpression - args[0]
                IdentifierName - ToLower
            ArgumentList - ()
        IdentifierName - StartsWith
    ArgumentList - ("x")
```

When in doubt, use the [Roslyn Quoter](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/), the full code it produces for your expression is:

```
InvocationExpression(
    MemberAccessExpression(
        SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
        InvocationExpression(
            MemberAccessExpression(
                SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
                ElementAccessExpression(
                    IdentifierName("args"))
                .WithArgumentList(
                    BracketedArgumentList(
                        SingletonSeparatedList<ArgumentSyntax>(
                            Argument(
                                LiteralExpression(
                                    SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression,
                                    Literal(0)))))),
                IdentifierName("ToLower"))),
        IdentifierName("StartsWith")))
.WithArgumentList(
    ArgumentList(
        SingletonSeparatedList<ArgumentSyntax>(
            Argument(
                LiteralExpression(
                    SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression,
                    Literal("x")))))))
```